# OnCreate() in a class (extend Application) is called very slowly

Tags: android

I call a method(below deleteCache method) in OnCreate() in a class which extend Application class. This method is for deleting files. It uses Thread because I want this method won't affect UI flow.

```
public static void deleteCache(final Context context) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                File dir = context.getCacheDir();
                deleteDir(dir);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

        }
    }).start();
}
```

But with this, the OnCreate() method in App class(extend Application) is called very slowly. So when I launch the app, it takes about 5 seconds to show a first Activity. 
I don't know why this happen. 
Please give me a any hint of this problem.

Comment: Use asynctask for this to do it in back ground.

Comment: How did you determine that this method was the problem?  What else does your `onCreate()` do?

Comment: When I don't call this method, this problem never happen.

Comment: I answer this question by myself. Maybe this problem happens because I delete some cache files. I confirm that if I delete cache files in OS app setting, then app launched with 5 seconds delay. There are some dex files in cache directory that occurred when app was launched. I think deleting this files is the cause of my problem. My app uses multidex features, so I guess this files exist.(I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Umer said, use AsyncTask if you run the in the UI-Thread. For Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Otherwise, if that won`t solve your problem, maybe your function is too complex or the data that will be deleted are very large.

Comment: Using AsyncTask don't solve this problem. Maybe you're right. My method is complex. But I called this in a Thread or AsyncTask, so I think even if this is complex, it shouln't have an any effect.

Comment: Consider that a smartphone does not have the computing power of a computer. When you`re working with recursive functions that invoke themselves a million times it sure affects the time. Furthermore checking conditions with if-clauses emphasizing this. My recommendation is to a) put in a logi, to overview how many times the methods are invoked (logi affects the runtime to) or to debug it by yourself and see what is happening

Comment: The weird thing is.. if this method take so long time.. why calling onCreate in Application is delayed? After onCreate is called, this deleteCache  method has completed so quickly.